# Test-Path on multiple computers of an AD

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, file-search

I'm trying to find out how to make a Test-Path against a list of computers via PowerShell and receive a "false" or "true" for each computer.

For example, to do something like this:

```
 $Computer = "OU=wsus,DC=server,DC=Com"
 Test-Path -Path "\$Computer\C$\Program Files\your app"
```

Result:

```
 computer1 = false computer2 = true computer3...
```

Is it possible or is there a better way to do it? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you getting the list from the AD LDAP path for all machines in that location? Where is the list of computers exactly, a file or those in that OU only? This is possible, I have slews of scripts I do similar things for mass deployments and post process checks. Help clarify the specific please.

Comment: I'm thinking of only testing the path in each machine located in the OU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Get-ADComputer` with the `-SearchBase` parameter with the LDAP OU path listing only the `Name` properties on the objects returned. Pipe those results over to a `ForEach-Object` loop then test if the machine is remotely accessible, and run other logic to output the results accordingly per machine.

**Basically though the conditional logic will work like so:**

1. If the machine in not remotely accessible to query, using conditional `If` to write a yellow message to the terminal indicating there is a connection issue with the specific machine not accessible.
2. If the machine is remotely accessible to query but the path to the folder or the executable file does not exist, write a red message to the terminal indicating the app does not exist.
3. If the machine is remotely accessible to query and the path to the folder or the executable file does exist, write a green message to the terminal indicating the app does exist.

**Note:** I personally prefer to check for the actual exe rather than just the folder as I've seen some software uninstall and leave a folder behind even though the software has been uninstalled—adjust accordingly.

### PowerShell

```
(Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=wsus,DC=server,DC=Com").Name | ForEach-Object { 
    If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Quiet -Count 1) {
        $app = "\\$_\C$\Program Files\your app\App.exe";
        If (Test-Path $app){Write-Host "The App does exist ==> $_" -ForegroundColor Green} Else {Write-Host "No App Exists ==> $_" -ForegroundColor Red};
    } Else {Write-Host "Not accessible to check ==> $_" -ForegroundColor Yellow}
};
```

### Output Examples

[image]

```
No App Exists ==> PC0001
No App Exists ==> PC0002
Not accessible to check ==> PC0003
Not accessible to check ==> PC0004
The App does exist ==> PC0005
The App does exist ==> PC0006
The App does exist ==> PC0007
The App does exist ==> PC0008
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-ADComputer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adcomputer?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-4-get-computer-accounts-in-a-specific-location-using-an-ldapfilter)
- [ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.3)
- [Test-Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-7.3)
- [Test-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-7.3)
- [If](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: @SergioYepes .... Let me know if you run into any issues or need further trivial adjustments. Good luck with this, but I think this will be a good starting point integrating in the LDAP OU path query stuff too. I figured that's what you needed based on how the logic in your question looked, but I wanted to confirm before posting an answer making an assumption on that important part.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
'127.0.0.1', 'localhost', $env:COMPUTERNAME | 
ForEach {
    Try   {Test-Path -Path "\\$PSItem\C$\Windows" -PathType Container -ErrorAction Stop}
    Catch {$Error[0].Exception}
}
# Results
<#
True
True
True
#>

'127.0.0.1', 'localhost', $env:COMPUTERNAME | 
ForEach {
    Try   {Test-Path -Path "\\$PSItem\C$\Test" -PathType Container -ErrorAction Stop}
    Catch {$Error[0].Exception}
}
# Results
<#
False
False
False
#>
```